# Question about Galaxy S3 Mini: Weird Problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

So, the back story is, I had a keyboard loaded on my s3 mini and I received an update from Samsung. Like every one get excited I was also excited and update my device but after I update I head over to send an email the keyboard which I have been using just disappeared. When I head over to the settings to find Keyboard the Samsung keyboard wasn't there? Now I am unable to type anything can some one help me out in sorting this problem out?

Comment: You could try installing a third-party keyboard for now.

Comment: @DanHulme Well, yes I can do that but what about the samsung stock keyboard? Does it mean that I can't user the stock Keyboard anymore?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options that I can think of.

1. Reinstall your ROM. Do it through `Odin` on PC or `Heimdall` on *NIX systems. This won't void your warranty, and will just install the ROM again. Ensure it is EXACTLY the correct one for your device / network. Check [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com) for your firmware.
2. Extract the keyboard. Download your firmware zip and extract the `keyboard.apk` and install it manually.
3. Find the apk online (HUGE security risk IMHO)
4. Use an alternative keyboard.
5. Try wiping your cache in recovery and rebooting see if it fixes the issue.
6. Check if the keyboard is there at all in your 'all apps' list and force start, clear data, reboot.  (There probably isn't, but look for Google Keyboard as well, no harm)

Comment: Well, this looks good ! Can I try performing a factory reset I have backup all my data and I guess I can... ! So,I was thinking if I perform a factory reset instead of flashing ROM... then is it going to help me ???

Comment: Factory reset **might** help but I'm dubious to be honest. If you flash your stock firmware over your current firmware all your apps should be unaffected, but  hopefully you'd get the keyboard back. Of course flashing ANY firmware carries a risk to it. It's really up to what you want to try and risk losing.